# Advice on dynamically generating list

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm new to coding in ASP, so your patience with me is appreciated.

I've built a user access request form which is working, however I now need to add a permissions section to it.

What this entails is 5 text boxes per row, but have it start with just one blank row, then if they fill in a row, another blank one appears below it.

Then when a button is clicked, the values are uploaded to my database.

This will also need to be populated if a user that already has access returns to the page.

Can this be done?

notes:
I'm using the EntityFramework, in .NET 4, with C#

Comment: You can do this via a number of techniques.  For example, you can do it with raw ASP.NET.  Or client-side JavaScript.  Really depends on you.  Also, this has nothing to do with the Entity Framework.  If I am to do this, I would choose client-side JavaScript as it is commonly used to perform something like this.  In ASP, you need to use postback to add a row.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  I don't really know javascript, so I might just go with the asp method..

Comment: Then take the answer by @Brijesh Mishra.  Add a new row on postback of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe put a button to add new row

Comment: I know this is going to sound dumb.. But how do you make a new row?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901120/dynamically-add-row-to-gridview-datagrid-repeater